# How to get the name of "folder" in KML

Tags: kml, openlayers-3

After displaying in OL3, I have to show in an HTML table; the name of folder and the name of placemark on KML

Here's the code to retrieve the name of the placemark:

```
vector.getSource (). forEachFeature (function (function) {
            var name = feature.getProperties() ['name'];});
```

So how is it to retrieve the folder name?

Thank you for your response